# Php how do i include @ in variable

Tags: php, json

`{
$myorganization->@type="Organization";//this point of view error
$myorganization->name="creative eyes";//this point of view error
}`

whenever i save it on and run it shows

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting identifier
>   (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in
>   /srv/disk7/2375751/www/xyz.com/index.php on line 436

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the @ symbol.  Can you show why you want it in a variable name which may help.

Answer (score 0):

`type` is not variable in that instance, so you can't use it there.

You'd have to do: `@$myorganization->type="Organization";//this point of view error`

Comment: The whole thing is like that and i must have to inclue @ but it throws error
$myObj->@age = 30; //this 
$myObj->city = "New York";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;